# Is it safe to mix pthread.h and C++11 standard library threading features?

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads, mutex

Can I spawn a thread with `pthread_create` and use `std::mutex` inside of it safely?

I would think that if `std::mutex` is implemented as a `pthread_mutex_t` then it would be fine but I don't see this documented anywhere

For example:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <mutex>

namespace {
std::mutex global_lock;
}

void* thread_func(void* vp) {
    // std::mutex used in thread spawned with pthread_create
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(global_lock);
    // critical section
    return nullptr;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, nullptr, thread_func, nullptr);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
}
```

BTW I'm running Debian Wheezy.

Comment: Spawning a thread and locking a mutex are two separate concepts. Is your question actually about mixing concurrency control from STL and PThread or just this one instance in particular?

Comment: @sixlettervariables mixing control in general.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the requirements/use case for this? Do you need to run the code from within C APIs? For this case this might be OK (since a C API running with pthread will need a pthread based C++ implementation).

Comment: @g-makulik I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  My particular use case isn't as much what I'm concerned with, as whether these can be mixed in general.  I don't intend to use any C API.  let's assume C++11 all the way through.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could on my machine (Debian too).  But I'm not sure if I would call this safe.

If you look at the relevant file, `/usr/include/c++/4.7/i486-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h` in my case, you will see that there will be a 1:1 mapping to the pthreads api. `<mutex>` uses `__gthread_mutex_lock` for locking which is defined exactly there to `pthread_mutex_lock`. Or you will see that `std::thread` declares `typedef __gthread_t native_handle_type;`

I don't know if there is a documented way to check if pthreads are used. But `gthr-default.h` defines `_GLIBCXX_GCC_GTHR_POSIX_H` as include guard and I think as long as this macro is defined, you can assume that you can mix them both.

Edit:  Given the hint from @Wakely, I would write:

```
template <typename T>
using strip = typename std::remove_pointer<typename std::decay<T>::type>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same<strip<std::thread::native_handle_type>, pthread_t>::value,
              "libstdc++ doesn't use pthread_t");
```

Comment: Don't rely on implementation details like that macro, it could change next release (something this broke Boost.Thread recently.) `std::is_same<std::thread::native_handle_type, pthread_t>` is a pretty good indicator Pthreads is used, although `native_handle_type` could be `pthread_t*` or another related type and the test would fail

Comment: Looks like `native_handle_type` isn't a pointer, and it is `pthread_t` on gcc on my platform, so the `strip` part isn't needed (but still cool, I didn't know you could do that).

Answer (score 7):

There's no guarentee in any spec that it will work, but it's likely that any C++ implementation on an OS that uses pthreads as its only real threading library will use pthreads underneath C++ threads, so it will likely work.

You will likely run into problems if you later try to port the code to some other platform that uses something other than pthreads, even if that platform supports pthreads too (eg, windows).

The questions is, why bother and risk it?  If you're using C++11 `std::mutex`, why not use `std::thread` as well?

Comment: I probably won't risk it, but I thought maybe it would be known to be safe.  The reasons for wanting this are a but contrived.  But let's just pretend that I'm using existing C++ code and updating it.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Why bother?  Because `pthread_create` supports customization via `pthread_attr_t` that `std::thread` doesn't

Comment: Even when the C++11 thread implementation isn't based on pthreads, it's very likely that any platform that has both APIs available implements them in terms of a common underlying platform API. Despite the lack of guarantee I think there is a reasonable expectation of practical portability. I think platforms lacking an implementation of one or the other will be *far* more common than platforms that implement the two APIs incompatibly.

Comment: `std::thread` does not provide any way to set or otherwise control the stack size.  So if you want to do that, you need to write non-portable code and carefully consult your implementation's documentation about how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Both `std::thread` and `std::mutex` have a `native_handle` method which allows you to dig down to the platform implementation of the given object. This says to me that the standard threading library is designed to play nice with the platform implementation.

As an aside `std::thread` and `std::mutex` are different objects that do different things viz. manage threads and provide cross thread synchronization. In the end the kernel does the heavy lifting.

So if you are not worried about portability, I cannot see why this should be an issue.

As an aside, sometimes you may need the native platform implementation so as to provide you with the richer feature-set that the platform allows. For example BSD threading allows different types of threads and some threading libraries allow you to set the stack size of your new thread. The C++ threading APIs are a portable lowest common denominator.

Comment: Maybe worth adding to this that threads, like processes, are implemented by the kernel on most/all operating systems that use pthreads (and probably most operating systems generally), meaning **there is really only one kind of thread** at the system level regardless of which userspace lib you use.  Not so sure about mutexes, but if I had to guess I'd say the same is true there.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is: can I use freely switch between one type of mutex and another at random? Then the answer is no (unless all the bottom layers use the same implementation, such as pthread_mutex.)

However, if you have different groups of resources that you want to protect, any one group of resources can be protected with any one implementation. Actually, it can at times be better to use a semaphore (i.e. semaphore are useful to define a one lock for write, many locks for reads).

So, if you have 4 groups of resources you are managing, you may use:

- std::mutex,
- pthread_mutex,
- boost::mutex,
- semaphores.

What you cannot do is use the boost::mutex to access data protected by the semaphores and vice versa, or std::mutex to use things protected by pthread_mutex.

As a simple example, in terms of code, this means a getter and a setter would be done this way:

```
void set(int new_value)
{
    guard lock(my_mutex);
    m_value = new_value;
}

int get() const
{
    guard lock(my_mutex);
    return m_value;
}
```

The two functions use the same mutex (here `my_mutex`) and obvious the mutex has **one** type.

Opposed to that, you could not do that:

```
void set(int new_value)
{
    guard lock(this_mutex_here);
    m_value = new_value;
}

int get() const
{
    SafeGuard lock(that_mutex_there);
    return m_value;
}
```

In this second example, you use two different mutexes and that won't work as expected because the lock in `set()` won't block the lock in `get()` and vice versa. So there is nothing safe about it (even if one of the guards is called SafeGuard.)

So the rule is, if you protect `m_value` with a mutex named `my_mutex`, any time you access `m_value` you must lock the `my_mytex` mutex. Which implementation you are using does not matter, as long as you are consistent in this way.