# C++ std::thread combined with C pthread_mutex_t

Tags: c++, pthreads

Just a quick question on which I didn't find clear answer:

Is it completely safe to create C++ `std::thread`s, in which I use `pthread_mutex_t` for locking critical sections?

**EDIT**: Mutexes locks parts of code to be safe from race conditioning. So I think it should have nothing to do with the matter of choosing C or C++ threads.

Comment: I don't know `std::thread`s but, I wouldn't do that even if I knew that it was very safe. Because `std::thread` is perhaps an abstraction that uses abstracted mutexes and other thread related things, just DON'T DO THAT. Instead read `std::thread`'s documentation and do it the right way, don't mix things like that ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it, that's what [std::mutex](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)'s are for, and if you want to further investigate you can google about all `std::thread` related things.

I consider it important to point out, that I have never used `std::thread`s in my life, but it's just a reasonable assumption that if there exists, `std::thread`, there must be a `std::mutex`, I typed `std::mutex` in google and the page in the link I posted in this answer appeared.

Comment: I know that `std::mutex` exists.. I am asking on combining two things in the title of question

Comment: The answer is don't do it, even if it works. Don't combine them. Either, use `pthread`s or `std::thread`s, but not both in the same program. It doesn't matter if it works, or if `std::mutex` is built with `pthread_mutex_t`, it's a matter of design and also good taste, DON'T, JUST DON'T! Not to mention, interoperability among the objects you use in your code.

Comment: Okay, thank you. You know why I am asking? In C++ you don't have implicitly implemented semaphores. Either you have to use C sempahores or go with some obstacle or something like that.

Comment: @scarface Interesting, then don't use c++

Comment: Not a solution - your last comment is a strange statement.

Comment: @scarface I am sorry, but it's not! If you can't use the language because it lacks this or that, then use another language. If you can't use `std::thread` because then, you have no semaphores, use `pthreads`, and so on. Don't use things that have the potential to be incompatible together. Also, [see why there are no standard semaphores](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4793662/1983495), because it's a simple thing to write one from the available objects, and you probably don't need one anyway

Comment: Whatever, thanks. I will wait for some time for some answers and then set your answer as the right one

Answer (score 1):

For portability, use `std::thread` and its associated structures like `std::mutex`. Minimize use of e.g. native handles etc. Using the `std::` mechanisms also makes your code less buggy, by using RAII. Without it, even experienced programmers forget to unlock locks at e.g. exceptions.

But here is a question similar to yours:
[Is it safe to mix pthread.h and C++11 standard library threading features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367988/is-it-safe-to-mix-pthread-h-and-c11-standard-library-threading-features)

Answer (score 0):

use std::mutex,

or, you can use std::atomic with std::thread

```
// std::atomic<UINT8> a;
thread t(f, std::ref(a));
t.detach();
```